# Dynamically generate map key in Grunt plugin config

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I use this code in grunt config:

```
const libDir = 'public/lib'
const cssDir = 'public/css'

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({

    watch: {
        scripts: {
            files: '**/*.js',
            tasks: ['default'],
        },
    },

    clean: [libDir],

    bower_concat: {
        all: {
            dest: {
                'js': libDir + '/vendor.js',
                'css': libDir + '/vendor.css'
            },
        }
    },

    sass: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                'output.css': 'input.scss'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How do I generate `output.css` dynamically by concatenating `cssDir` and some string ?

I tried using templating but it ignores `cssDir`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that ES6 supports dynamic property keys so basically this solves the problem as I can now compute both the key and value as `dirVar + 'outputFile': inputDir + 'input.file'`

Answer (score 1):

Templates are not expanded for all config properties and especially not for config keys.

Since Grunt files are basically Javascript programs, you can construst the object programmatically:

```
const cssDir = 'public/css';

var sassFilesMap = {};

// build sass output file mapping programmatically
sassFilesMap[cssDir + "/output.scss"] = "input.scss";

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    // ...

    sass: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true
        },
        dist: {
            files: sassFilesMap
        }
    }
});
```

If there are multiple `.scss` files to be converted (to be configured) you might with something like this:

```
const sassMappings = [["edit.scss", "edit.css"], ["public.scss", "public.css"]];

sassMappings.forEach(function(pair) {
    // pair[0] is the .scss filename, pair[1] is the .css filename
    sassFilesMap[cssDir + "/" + pair[0]] = pair[1];
});
```